# When can printed values in gdb be incorrect?

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

Some days ago I encountered an odd bug in my code where apparently the variable `pi` (see below) had the value 0, as the line `lat += 0.5 * pi` did nothing, but `lat += 1` worked as expected. The bug vanished after changing the compiler version (from GCC 5.3.1 to GCC 6.2.1 on CentOS 6), but what intrigued me the most was that when using gdb, when arriving at a set breakpoint at that position, `print pi` output the expected `3.141`, though still `lat += 0.5 * pi` did not change the value of `lat` in any way. Internally, somehow, the value for `pi` within gdb did not match the value within the program.

It is deeply unsatisfying that the bug vanishes when changing my toolchain and I don't know where the error came from (probably I did something wrong or at least in a bad way). However, under what circumstances can't I trust the values given to me in gdb? Can the external linkage of `pi` be a trap for debugging purposes?

```
// Constant.h
#pragma once
namespace abc {
    const double pi = 3.141;
}

// Code.h
#pragma once
namespace abc {
    extern const double pi;
    int lat_func(double& lat);
}

// Code.cpp
#include "Constant.h"
#include "Code.h"
#include <iostream>
namespace abc {
    int lat_func(double& lat) {
        std::cout << "pi: " << pi << std::endl; // `pi: 0`
        // When setting a breakpoint here, `p pi` returns `3.141` in gdb
        lat += 0.5 * pi; // lat is unchanged
        lat += 1; // 1 is added to lat
        return 0;
    }
}

// main.cpp
#include "Code.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    double lat = 0.5;
    abc::lat_func(lat);
    std::cout << lat << std::endl;
}
```

Code.cpp is part of a static library that main.cpp is linked against.

Edit: The Makefile used is

```
INCLUDES = -I.
LIBS = -L. -lcode
CC = g++
CCFLAGS = -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11

all: libcode.a main

main: main.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

libcode.a: Code.o
    ar cr $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -fPIC -c -o $@ $<
```

Edit: As suggested in the comments, this is the disassembled code of the line `lat += 0.5 * pi`. The difference between both of them (as far as I can see) is that in GCC 5.3.1, `pxor   %xmm2,%xmm2` is called at one point and in GCC 6.2.1, this changes to `movsd  0xcfee57d(%rip),%xmm2`.

**GGC 5.3.1**

```
          lat += 0.5 * pi;
=> 0x0000000000f1c22c <+312>: mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000f1c230 <+316>: movsd  (%rax),%xmm1
   0x0000000000f1c234 <+320>: pxor   %xmm2,%xmm2
   0x0000000000f1c238 <+324>: movsd  0x1269a0(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x1042be0
   0x0000000000f1c240 <+332>: mulsd  %xmm2,%xmm0
   0x0000000000f1c244 <+336>: addsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x0000000000f1c248 <+340>: mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000f1c24c <+344>: movsd  %xmm0,(%rax)
```

**GCC 6.2.1**

```
          lat += 0.5 * pi;
=> 0x0000000000f34ca3 <+327>: mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000f34ca7 <+331>: movsd  (%rax),%xmm1
   0x0000000000f34cab <+335>: movsd  0xcfee57d(%rip),%xmm2        # 0xdf23230 <_ZN3abc2piE>
   0x0000000000f34cb3 <+343>: movsd  0x127735(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x105c3f0
   0x0000000000f34cbb <+351>: mulsd  %xmm2,%xmm0
   0x0000000000f34cbf <+355>: addsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x0000000000f34cc3 <+359>: mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000f34cc7 <+363>: movsd  %xmm0,(%rax)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on my side with g++ 5.4.0 and gdb 7.11.1? What is the printed result you obtain at the end with gdb? Since you can't set a breakpoint on a blank line, did you set the breakpoint for `lat += 1` wrongly, and thus did not see a change in `lat`?

Comment: I `step`ped through the complete function after setting a breakpoint at the line before `lat += 0.5 * pi` and looked at the value of `pi` and `lat` at every step. gdb correctly sees that `lat` was not increased when using `pi` and also correctly sees the increase when using `+= 1`. The value for `lat` in gdb and in the program are always the same, the value for `pi`, however, is not. That's why I'm asking if there are possibilities when gdb prints wrong values for externally linked variables.

Comment: Again, I was not able to reproduce this. Have you tried to concatenate all files into one, and see if that changes anything? Also, have you tried to use different variable names?

Comment: What flags do you pass to the compiler and linker? Optimizations may make the debug information somewhat less reliable.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Concatenating I did not yet try as the actual library used is a bit bigger. Renaming the variables does not help. @PaulR I added the Makefile I used, everything is passed `-O0`. Again, I'm more interested in the situations where gdb might give wrong answers than any programming error on my part.

Comment: Can you show us the disassembled code (with gdb's `disas /m`) for `lat_func`, working and non-working? It might be quicker than one of us setting up a copy of your environment (I guess you're using the Developer Toolset versions of gcc).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I added the disassembled code to my post; the devtoolset-4 (you were right with that assumption) makes a call to `pxor %xmm2,%xmm2` whereas devtoolset-6 compiles into `movsd  0xcfee57d(%rip),%xmm2`.

Comment: Looks like it's calculating `lat += 0.0 * pi`. Red Hat supports devtoolset-4 until November, so you can file a bug report if you wish. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/buglist.cgi?component=gcc&product=Red%20Hat%20Developer%20Toolset&resolution=---

Answer (score 2):

There can certainly be bugs in GDB and in GCC (which must provide the correct DWARF information, otherwise GDB will not work).

How did you determine that the `lat += 0.5 * pi;` statement executed?  What often happens (at least in optimized code) is that you step over a line like this, but GDB only executes its partially (say, just the multiplication, or the computation of the address), and eventually returns to it after a few more steps.  Then the addition might be performed, and after that, the store.

Complex statements like this one result in multiple machine instructions, and GCC schedules them independently, interleaving them with other instructions.  With the way GCC currently generates debugging information for optimized code, it is not possible to represent that in a way that debugging with GDB is straightforward.

Arguably, this is a GCC/GDB bug, but it's not easy to fix.  A recent blog post, [Statement Frontier Notes and Location Views](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/07/11/statement-frontier-notes-and-location-views/), explains how the GNU toolchain folks plan to tackle this.

**EDIT** After thinking about this some more, the most likely explanation is that this is simply a GCC bug, where it simply does not process the `pi` variable correctly.  GDB looks at the variable in memory, and finds the expected value stored there, but for some reason, the machine code GCC generated does not load it correctly.  If this is a compiler bug, then it is useless to speculate about GDB behavior because anything can happen with a compiler bug (and when confronted with such bugs, the only thing you can do to debug it is look at the generated machine code and dump files containing intermediate compiler information).

Comment: The code was compiled by passing `-g -O0` to the compiler, so no optimizations should have occurred, if I understand correctly. When `step`ping through the code, the line `lat += 0.5 * pi` appears as an instruction. Does this not guarantee it to be executed? Thank you for the link!

Comment: If the code was indeed compiled with `-g -O0`, then this smells like a GCC or GDB bug. What do you mean with “appears as an instruction”? The line compiles to multiple instructions (with `-O0`, GCC will not use a fused multiply-add). You need to `step` a couple of times (beyond a pointer where `lat` is definitely needed) and see if execution appears to jump back to the line with the assignment.

Comment: I mean that gdb shows the line (including line number) while stepping through the function body. `lat` is defined, `pi` is defined (and set to a non-zero value in gdb) and the line is shown as it is written in the function at the expected position of the function. Sorry, if I misused the term "instruction".

Comment: Just try `step`ping further and see what happens. As I tried to explain, execution is not linear—if optimization is enabled. To be clear, I don't expect a GCC/GDB bug here, but that for some reason, your code was still compiled with optimization.

Comment: Because of my cout within the function body, I know that `pi` had the value  0 in the program, but 3.141 in the debugger. If I step through my whole program, I never see the `lat += 0.5 * pi` taking any effect, since, for whatever reason, `pi == 0`. I assume that I don't use the external linkage correctly, but the discrepancy between gdb and program really threw me off. I just want to know if it there are known limits to gdb and its printed values of variables and that I should be ready for such a situation. The `-g -O0` is part of all targets in my Makefile, so no optimization takes place.

Comment: Okay, you are right, this is probably a compiler bug. But once you hit one of these, all bets are off because the debugging information could be inconsistent as well (which appears to be the case here). I tried to explain this in my edit.